# Who can invoke pikuach nefesh?

Tags: pikuachnefesh-danger-life

In today's news (18 March 2020), the Sephardic Chief Rabbi of Israel [ruled](https://www.jpost.com/Israel-News/Chief-Rabbi-Leave-phones-on-during-Shabbat-621504) that Jews may use their cellphones on Shabbat to receive developments and alerts regarding the coronavirus.

This is an invocation of pikuach nefesh to enable people to receive news that *might* save their own lives' or others'.

Does the invocation of pikuach nefesh to break Shabbat *have to* come from a rabbi (***if there is time to consult one*),** or can it be a personal decision?  What is the halacha?

Comment: If there is time one usually asks a rabbi but it is unnecessary.

Comment: Do modern rabbis have any special halachik status different than any other person?

Answer (score 2):

See [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1113745/jewish/Saving-Lives-on-Shabbat.htm)

> One who is faced with a situation that might be construed as a matter
>   of pikuach nefesh, and goes to consults with a rabbi about the
>   situation is considered a murderer—because due to his excessive
>   "piety," and the resultant delay in implementing the proper measures,
>   he might be endangering a life. And the rabbi who is asked is
>   disgraceful—because he should have taught his community the proper
>   manner of action when dealing with pikuach nefesh, i.e., to take
>   action without delay.

Comment: Your answer refers only to a urgent/ time sensitive situation when there is not time to ask. That is not the case referred to in the question